# Move Selected elements of a Map up or down

Tags: java, collections, arraylist, linkedhashmap, generic-collections

I am trying to modify a list of elements in a `Map` by moving the selected items up or down. My idea is to remember the elements next to selected items. Because the elements are in a map, I find it much difficult to do it though I use a `LinkedHashMap` 
I would greatly appreciate if anyone can give me an idea about how to do it.

**Note:** I have generalized the question and below code is just a reference.

```
public void moveUp(ActionEvent evt) {
    List<String> selectedItems = myBean().getSelectedItems();
    if(selectedItems.isEmpty()) return;
    Map<String, String> avlbleItems = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>(myBean().getListBoxItems());
    List<String> avlbleItemsList = new ArrayList<String>(myBean().getListBoxItems().values());
    int size = avlbleItems.size();
    List<String> tail = new ArrayList();
    List<String> head = new ArrayList();
    int buf = 0,k = 0,j = 0,m = 0,n = 0;
    try {
        label:
        for (Iterator it = selectedItems.iterator(); it.hasNext();buf++) {
            String st = (String) it.next();
            if(buf==0) {
                for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                    if(avlbleItemsList.get(i).equals(st)) {
                        k = i-1;
                        m = k+2;
                        n = m;
                    }
                }
                if(k < 0) return;
                if(k == 0) continue label; 
            }
            if(n < size && selectedItems.contains(avlbleItemsList.get(n))) {
                n++;
            }
            if(k+2 < size && !selectedItems.contains(avlbleItemsList.get(k+2))) {
                m++;
            }
            if(!it.hasNext()) {
                for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                    if(avlbleItemsList.get(i).equals(st)) {
                        j = i+1;
                        if(j == size) break label;
                        if(j < size) {
                            tail = avlbleItemsList.subList(j, size);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        avlbleItems.clear();
        for (Iterator ite = head.iterator(); ite.hasNext();) {
            String st = (String) ite.next();
            avlbleItems.put(st, st);
        }
        for (Iterator it = selectedItems.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
            String st = (String) it.next();
            avlbleItems.put(st, st);
        }
        avlbleItems.put(avlbleItemsList.get(k), avlbleItemsList.get(k));
        for (int i = n; i < j-1; i++) {
            avlbleItems.put(avlbleItemsList.get(i), avlbleItemsList.get(i));
        }
        for (Iterator it = tail.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
            String st = (String) it.next();
            avlbleItems.put(st, st);
        }
    } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
        handleException();
        return;
    } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
        handleException();
        return;
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        handleException();
        return;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, what you are trying to do with the Map is really best done as a Linked List (where you can move an element trivially up or down).  I would suggest instead of all of this complicated machinery you make a simple class that extends a Linked List and has a HashMap as a member.  Then you can override the add, delete, and clear methods so that they also add/delete/clears both the super linked list, and the HashMap.

This will get you both the benefits of the HashMap and a linked list, and conceptually will be easier to deal with.

Answer (score 1):

A `Map` has no concept of order. There is no "next to", "up" or "down" in a `Map`.

If you want an order-preserving `Map` you can use `LinkedHashMap`, which is based on insertion order, or define your own implementation that imposes whatever order you want.  If you want order to be defined by the keys, then a `TreeMap` may be appropriate, but then if you change an item's key you would have to remove it and reinsert it.